# how to mark crossovers on a moving average chart with an offset

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, indicator

```
`ndicator(title="Williams Alligator", shorttitle="Alligator", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
smma(src, length) =>
    smma =  0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
jawLength = input.int(13, minval=1, title="Jaw Length")
teethLength = input.int(8, minval=1, title="Teeth Length")
lipsLength = input.int(5, minval=1, title="Lips Length")
jawOffset = input(8, title="Jaw Offset")
teethOffset = input(5, title="Teeth Offset")
lipsOffset = input(3, title="Lips Offset")
jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = smma(hl2, teethLength)
lips = smma(hl2, lipsLength)
plot(jaw, "Jaw", offset = jawOffset, color=#2962FF)
plot(teeth, "Teeth", offset = teethOffset, color=#E91E63)
plot(lips, "Lips", offset = lipsOffset, color=#66BB6A)

plotshape(ta.crossover(lips,jaw), style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, size = size.small)
plotshape(ta.crossunder(teeth,jaw), style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.small)
```

I need the indicator to give a buy signal when the green line (lips) crosses the blue one (jaw), and give a sell signal when the red line (teeth) crosses the blue one (jaw). My indicator gives me signals too early. Help me please to solve the problem.
[Here is the picture what i get and what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEmZd.png)

Answer (score 0):

The jaw/teeth/lips plots on the chart are using offset to the right, while ta.cross*() functions take into account the values without offset. You need to offset the values to the past to match the plots on the chart:

```
plotshape(ta.crossover(lips[lipsOffset],jaw[jawOffset]), style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, size = size.small)
plotshape(ta.crossunder(teeth[teethOffset],jaw[jawOffset]), style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.small)
```

The shapes will plot the next bar after the cross:
[image]